# Clip raster by mask layer gdalwarp error in QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster, extract-by-mask

I've been trying to find why my gdalwarp isn't allowing me to clip a raster to the shape of a shapefile.

GDAL command:
gdalwarp -ot Byte -of GTiff -cutline /Users/johnmorris/Desktop/Geodata/StudyArea.shp -crop_to_cutline -dstnodata 0.0 /Users/johnmorris/Desktop/Geodata/TotalRevenueDraft. /var/folders/z4/bpntn2_964d4hvl5l37wfny80000gn/T/processing_cce36f0eaee64b1aa98a58af4c157ad2/9ca388a9371f44deb2fa4eab49ba0026/OUTPUT.tif
GDAL command output:
/bin/sh: gdalwarp: command not found

Execution completed in 0.08 seconds
Results:
{'OUTPUT': }

Loading resulting layers
The following layers were not correctly generated.
/var/folders/z4/bpntn2_964d4hvl5l37wfny80000gn/T/processing_cce36f0eaee64b1aa98a58af4c157ad2/9ca388a9371f44deb2fa4eab49ba0026/OUTPUT.tif
You can check the 'Log Messages Panel' in QGIS main window to find more information about the execution of the algorithm.

It keeps saying it doesn't understand the command gdalwarp. I have GDAL 2.3.1 installed and am using QGIS 3.0.3

Please help!

Comment: Is this on OSX?

Comment: Yes, sorry forgot to mention.